# How to create user controls with parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know there is a way to create a user control in ASP.NET that has a parameter when added to the page markup.

Can anyone tell me how to it? It is OK if you can't provide code. Just the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your user control, create a public property, e.g. like this:

```
public int MyIntProperty { get; set; }
```

Then you can access it whenever you use your user control.

Answer (score 2):

You could [use properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s70936s.aspx).